# Cluster(Multi server) setup for zookeeper exhibitor

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm newbie to Zookeeper.Trying to setup clustering server for zookeeper exhibitor to modify the data. I have tried the server setup with 3 nodes, but data modification not reflected on all the zookeeper.

I refereed the following url & also setup the server in the same way. But no use, some thing i'm missing in that config to run it correctly.

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup

Exhibitor startup command is:

**java -jar exhibitor-war-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar -c file --nodemodification true --port 9090**

Farther I need to add any other config with this to get my data modification reflect on all the zookeeper.

Advance thanks for ur kind time!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar scenario, and I'm on Windows. So I get some problems due to the fact that Exhibitor is Unix-oriented - it tries to restart zkServer.sh (instead of zkServer.bat). So I:
 1. have manually started ZK ensemble (all instances get data modifications from each other).
 2. set up Exhibitor above every ZK instance - with single network config file.

Hope it helps. If not, give more details.